# Connecting old 3.5'' HDD to laptop

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an old 3.5'' HDD, I have an IDE HDD to USB cable connector and a power cable. I'm plugging the whole thing to my laptop. Windows says device successfully installed but I can't find the drive in My Computer.

I Tried to initialize it through Device Manager but I get the error message "Drive not ready"! Any ideas?

Comment: Check Disk Management. Does this drive have any important data on it?

Comment: Are you sure the drive works?  Sounds like the drive is dead and all thats being detected is the USB Controller.

Comment: Power up the drive and wait about 5 seconds before you plug in the USB cable on the laptop.  The HDD must be ready before the USB negotiation begins.  Disconnect in reverse order.